# Border in circle UIView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I'm trying to make an UIView with border but I only make it appear in UIView not only on the circle.

[image: sample]

In the brown circle I want a black border, but it has to be in the circle not in the UIView.

I have a class called Ball where I draw the circle.

```
class Ball: UIView {

    var desiredColour = UIColor.blueColor()

    struct mine {
        static var p = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0,0,118,117))

    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code


        desiredColour.setFill()
        mine.p.fill()

    }


    func colour() {

        var randColor: UIColor = Colors.randomColor()

        Colors.ballColor = randColor
        Colors.colorPosition = find(Colors.arrayColors, randColor)!

        desiredColour = randColor
        self.setNeedsDisplay()

    }
}
```

I used the code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code


    desiredColour.setFill()

    let desiredBorderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    desiredBorderColor.setStroke()

    self.layer.borderWidth  = 3.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2.0

    mine.p.fill()
    mine.p.stroke()

}
```

but i get a border with a little cuts:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @matt i improve the question, see if u can understand now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code


        desiredColour.setFill()

        let desiredBorderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        desiredBorderColor.setStroke()

        mine.p.lineWidth = 2.0 //set to whatever you want

        mine.p.fill()
        mine.p.stroke()

    }
```

But note that for border to work you need to have some space around you circle.

Do the following. Declare `myBorderWidth` (of type `CGFloat`) property and then change

```
static var p = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0,0,118,117))
```

to

```
static var p = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(myBorderWidth/2,myBorderWidth/2,118-myBorderWidth/2,117-myBorderWidth/2))
```

You can also remove repetitions of `myBorderWidth/2` by declaring it as a property.

Comment: see the result in my question update, it cuts some parts of the border

Comment: @marchiore the width of the border is calculated from the edges of your circle. So, if you put 10 it will cut them severely because 5 point further away will be outside of your uiview. You need to ensure that there is some space around your circle

Answer (score 10):

Try calling this function by passing you view as a parameter

```
func drawBlackBorder(view: UIView) {
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width/2.0
       view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify layer, just set up UIBezierPath with proper insets depending on border thickness and set it's width (tested on Swift 4.2):

```
var fillColor: UIColor //circle color
var strokeColor: UIColor //border color
var borderWidth: CGFloat //border width

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    fillColor.setFill()
    strokeColor.setStroke()

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: borderWidth, y: borderWidth, width: rect.width - borderWidth*2, height: rect.height - borderWidth*2))
    circlePath.lineWidth = borderWidth

    circlePath.stroke()
    circlePath.fill()
}
```